# How to give padding to items from parent in react

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm using css-module to style react , i have a css file like this

```
.button-style {
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

And an simple react file like this

```
import React from "react"
import { useEffect, useState, useCallback, useMemo } from "react"
import style from "./styleHook.module.css"
export default function TestEffect() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1)
  const [color, setColor] = useState("black")
  const increaseCount = () => setCount(count + 1)
  const double = (count: number) => count * 2
  const changeColor = (color: string) => {
    console.log("uh oh,this will re-render")
    color === "black" ? setColor("blue") : setColor("black")
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("hey count just change and i show up")
  }, [count])

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Value of double count : {count}</h1>
      <h2 style={{ color: color }}>This text have {color} color!</h2>
      <div className={style['button-style']}>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setCount(count + 1)
          }}
        >
          Change value
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            changeColor(color)
          }}
        >
          Change color
        </button>
        <button onClick={increaseCount}>Increase count by 1</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now i want to give some space **between** button, but don't know how but it give padding for parent instead of child, come from `react-native` and i feel like it not work like `react-native`

Please help, here is the codesandbox demo

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-fast-s02mi?file=/src/styleHook.module.css)

Comment: The link to Sandbox you provided, is broken

Comment: i just update the link

Comment: See https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-morse-s60w7

Answer (score 1):

add margin to buttons

button {
margin: 0 5px;
}

Comment: Thank for your answer, but if i want only apply style for these button, how can i do that?

Comment: Your demo does not work, I can help you if you can make you demo work

Comment: That weird, i can run on my machine, let me see

Comment: here https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-franklin-ebwbn?file=/src/index.js

Comment: @LêQuốcKhánh, look at this, I add button-style to css file.  https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-herschel-uspp0?file=/src/styles.module.css

Comment: But can we just and custom amount of space, for example 10px, 20px?

Comment: @LêQuốcKhánh. look at the code sandbox again

Answer (score 1):

You can put these buttons into a div and apply grid property on that div.
Like this

```
 <div style={{display:'grid', gridTemplateColumns:'repeat( auto-fit,minmax(250px, 1fr)', gap:'10px'}}>
     <button1>1</button1>
     <button2>2</button1>
     <button3>3</button1>
    </div>
```

Now they are responsive as well.

Comment: Thank you so much, but that ...too much too, im trying to understand basic css

Comment: {dislay:flex, justifyContent:"space-between'} on that div.

Comment: No i mean, just add some space, a certain amount of them, like 10px or 20px